# How to count sum of values from json objects in certain subdirectories seperately

Tags: php, json, foreach, sum

I have 3 directories named `september`, `october` and `november` in the maindirectory `2021`.
In all these 3 directories are json files which look like this:

```
{
    "id": "id_2021-09-05_2200",
    "date": "2021-09-05",
    "guests": 32 // total guests for that day
}
```

For every month, i need the sum of all `guests` for that month. ( count all guests from all the json files in that month together).

I have this code so far but i get stuck in counting for each month:

```
$monthdirs = array_filter(glob('data/2021/*'), 'is_dir'); // read all month-dirs in year 2021
foreach($monthdirs as $monthdir) {
    $monthfiles = glob($monthdir.'/*.json');    // all json files in a specific month
}
foreach($monthfiles as $monthfile) {
        $arr[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($monthfile),true); // php assoc array
        foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
            $tot_guests_monthes[] += $val['guests'];    // new array from each month with the sum of guests from all the json files in that month 
        }
}
foreach($tot_guests_monthes as $tot_guests_month) {
    echo $tot_guests_month.'<br />';
}
```

I think in the 2nd foreach loop i am doing something wrong. My final output should be 3 values, something like:

```
200 // all guests september
300 // all guests october
400 // all guests november
```

Comment: What's wrong with the input you're getting from your current code?

Comment: i got more then 3 values as output; so the code is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$...[] =` is basically a [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), which means that `$tot_guests_monthes[] += $val['guests'];` will create a new element for each element of `$arr` of each `$monthfile` instead of summing.

Summing all values in a month and then adding them to `$tot_guests_monthes` should work:

```php
$tot_guests_monthes = [];

$monthdirs = array_filter(glob('data/2021/*'), 'is_dir'); // read all month-dirs in year 2021
foreach($monthdirs as $monthdir) {
    $monthfiles = glob($monthdir.'/*.json');    // all json files in a specific month
    
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($monthfiles as $monthfile) {
        $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($monthfile), true);
        $sum += $arr['guests'];
    }
    $tot_guests_monthes[] = $sum;
}

foreach($tot_guests_monthes as $tot_guests_month) {
    echo $tot_guests_month.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I got a 500 error with this code

Comment: I have updated the answer, it contained a syntax error. Does the current version work?

Comment: no unfortunately, still got a 500 with the updated code

Comment: `$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($monthfile),true);` should be `$arr[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($monthfile),true);`. Now the error is gone, but still not the correct values

Comment: Spetmber should give me: `82`, october `313` and november `1315`. And with this code i get: `304`, `2166`, `7570`

Comment: Ah, wait. Your month files don't contain arrays but objects, so we don't need the foreach, I think that is the issue here. Does this latest edit do the trick?

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect now!